# How to select a random line in a listbox then save it to a file with the click of a button in C#?

Tags: c#

How do I select a random line from a listbox then output it to a savefile with the click of a button? I need it for a calculator program that will have a button that selects a random line (output of the calculations) then save it to a file using Savefile dialog.

Comment: Depends on the UI framework. Which UI framework is used? Also please show the code how the ListBox and Button are defined.

Comment: I'm on visual studio 2017 net.framework for C#. This is my code so far:

Comment: It wont let me add my code.

Comment: @JackWilliams update your question with the code

Comment: `File.AppendAllText(saveDialog.FileName, listBox1.Items[new Random().Next(listBox1.Items.Count)].ToString());`